# ISO c++ 15.3.10 : Why is this undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

From the related c++ standard section :

> Referring to any non-static member or base class of an object in the handler for a function-try-block of a constructor or destructor for that object results in undefined behavior.

eg.

```
T::~T() 
{
      try {
        this->nonstatic_member; // iff I read the quote correctly
      } catch( ... ) {
      }
}
```

So why is this undefined behaviour ?

Comment: It is not, because this is not a function-try-block.

Comment: @n.m. Just stumbled upon this, could you provide a correct reading of the quote (preferably involving a destructor) ?

Comment: Uh, that should be something like `T::~T() try { }catch(...)` [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4d070aebae60ef9)

Comment: The one-word answer: Don't use function-try-blocks.

Comment: @KerrekSB Don't know, there's no abolishment of them in the [usual](http://www.drdobbs.com/introduction-to-function-try-blocks/184401297) references and I've been reading on it all morning (the [Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25094250/2567683) you answered is what actually got me here). Maybe a new question on the topic would be useful but probably will be close as a dup [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612486/when-is-a-function-try-block-useful)

Comment: I'm not saying that they should be abolished (though they're perfectly useless), only that you shouldn't use them :-)

Comment: @CodyGray if you click on the last word of my previous comment I also mention the same post :) though I'm highly tempted to ask so that someone will expose all the cons (have the q ready already)

Comment: Oh hah! So you do. Sorry about that. The visited link color is almost impossible to distinguish from regular text on my screen, and it's worse for links with only a few characters. Anyway, maybe you could ask the question a different way. Instead of "when is it useful?", ask what can go wrong. Even better if you can contextualize it somehow, to avoid asking a list-style question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the reason why accessing non-static data members in a function-try-block of a *destructor* is that [except.ctor]/2 and [except.handle]/11 guarantee that all subobjects have already been destroyed when entering the catch-clause of said try-block:

> **github draft from 2014-07-23, [except.ctor]/2**
>
> An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction
> is terminated by an exception will have destructors executed for all
> of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of
> a union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal
> constructor has completed execution and the destructor has not yet
> begin execution.
>
> **[except.handle]/11**
>
> [...] The base classes and non-variant members of
> an object shall be destroyed before entering the handler of a
> *function-try-block* of a destructor for that object.

Therefore, whether we throw the exception in the dtor of the class itself, or in the dtor of a subobject: all subobjects will be destroyed.

---

### Example 1:

```
#include <iostream>

struct loud
{
    ~loud() { std::cout << "~loud()\n"; }
};

struct T
{
    loud l;
    
    ~T() noexcept(false)
    try
    {
        std::cout << "throwing an int\n";
        throw 42;
    }catch(int)
    {
        std::cout << "caught an int\n";
        throw;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        T t;
    }catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "caught an exception in main\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
throwing an int
~loud()
caught an int
caught an exception in main
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a34c055dcd27303)</kbd>

---

### Example 2:

```
#include <iostream>

struct loud
{
    loud() { std::cout << "loud()\n"; }
    ~loud() { std::cout << "~loud()\n"; }
};

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A()\n"; }
    ~A() noexcept(false) { std::cout << "~A()\n"; throw 42; }
};

struct T
{
    loud l;
    A a;
    
    ~T() noexcept(false)
    try
    {
    }catch(int)
    {
        std::cout << "caught an int\n";
        throw;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        T t;
    }catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "caught an exception in main\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
loud()
A()
~A()
~loud()
caught an int
caught an exception in main
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acb5140a81b1f6da)</kbd>

Comment: The same reasoning probably applies to constructors: The fully-constructed bases and members are destructed before entering a function-try-block's catch-clause.

Answer (score 6):

A non-static member can be either yet non-created or already destroyed when the handler is processed.

And your example does not demonstrate a function-try-block. It is a try-block inside the body of the destructor when neither subobject is yet destroyed.

Here an example of a function-try block for a constructor

```
T::T(int ii, double id)
try : i(f(ii)), d(id) 
{
   // constructor statements
}
catch (...) 
{
   // handles exceptions thrown from the ctor-initializer
   // and from the constructor statements
}
```

Comment: Apart from the base class subobjects; why is it UB to access the non-static data members in a function-try-block of a dtor? Their order of destruction is guaranteed, so couldn't you infer which ones are still alive?

Comment: @dyp Usually the Standard considers general cases.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
struct S
{
    S() try
    : m()
    {

    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // this->non_static is UB
    }

    ~S()
    try
    {

    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // this->non_static is UB
    }
private:
    Member m;
};
```

When you are in the catch block you cannot be sure from where the exception come from and so which object is initialized/destroyed.

Comment: *"When you are in the catch block you cannot be sure from where the exception come from"* In the general case, yes, but you could have distinct exception types for you different members; or some members whose dtors are noexcept etc. The order of destruction is guaranteed. Same question as I asked on Vlad's answer.

Comment: @dyp The [construction tracker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22260634/2567683) idiom lets you know where the exception came from (at least for constructors)